# Woocommerce checkout page redirecting to homepage?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

All plugins deactivated except for Woocommerce.

I have a page called "Checkout Page" and under Woocommerce > Settings > Checkout, that page is set for the Checkout page

But when I go to view that page, it redirects to the homepage.  I can't access the page unless I change the page set under the Checkout page setting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to add WooCommerce shortcode for checkout on that page? Most importantly did you add any product to cart?

Comment: @Fresz - yes to adding the shortcode for checkout to the page.  No, I didn't add any products.  I don't even have a cart page.  But why would a lack of products cause a redirect to the homepage?

Comment: Because u cant checkout empty order. Make sure u have set shop page as well. Try adding one product and do it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cart page or checkout page wont work for two reasons.

1. Shop page is not set in WooCommerce options.
2. You didn't add any products to cart so you cant pay for nothing. (Also happens when product price is set to 0)

It will redirect to homepage when shop page is not set (not fully sure about this).

Answer (score 1):

Just for others who don't want checkout to redirect if cart is empty.

Add these two lines in your functions.php or into any snippet plugin.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_redirect_empty_cart', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review_expired', '__return_false' );
```